# Doctrine2 many-to-one association won't use JOIN query

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have a `Car` entity with a many-to-one relationship with an entity `Owner`. If I select all cars, Doctrine does one query on the `Car` table, and subsequently one query on the `Owner` table *for each car*. So fetching N cars becomes N+1 queries instead of a single JOIN query between the `Car` and `Owner` tables.

My entities are as follows:

```
/** @Entity */
class Car {

  /** @Id @Column(type="smallint") */
  private $id;

  /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Owner", fetch="EAGER")
      @JoinColumn(name="owner", referencedColumnName="id") */
  private $owner;

  public function getId()    { return $this->id; }
  public function getOwner() { return $this->owner; }
}

/** @Entity */
class Owner {

  /** @Id @Column(type="smallint") */
  private $id;

  /** @Column(type="string") */
  private $name;

  public function getName() { return $this->name; }
}
```

If I want to list the cars with their owners, I do:

```
$repo = $em->getRepository('Car');
$cars = $repo->findAll();

foreach($cars as $car) 
  echo 'Car no. ' . $car->getId() . 
       ' owned by ' . $car->getOwner()->getName() . '\n';
```

Now this all works very well, apart from the fact that Doctrine issues a query for each car.

```
SELECT * FROM Car;
SELECT * FROM Owner WHERE id = 1;
SELECT * FROM Owner WHERE id = 2;
SELECT * FROM Owner WHERE id = 3;
....
```

Of course I'd want my query log to look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Car JOIN Owner ON Car.owner = Owner.id;
```

Whether I have `fetch="EAGER"` or `fetch="LAZY"` doesn't matter, and even if I make a custom DQL query with JOIN between the two entities, `$car->getOwner()` still causes Doctrine to query the database (unless I use EAGER, in which case `$repo->findAll()` causes all of them).

Am I just too tired here, and this is the way it is supposed to work - or is there a clever way to force Doctrine to do the JOIN query instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least in 1.x Doctrine if you wanted to query for the related objects, you had to use DQL. For your case, the DQL query would look something like this:

```
//Assuming $em is EntityManager
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT c, o FROM Car c JOIN c.owner o');
$cars = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Looks like that is also the case in 2.x. I had tried the query `SELECT c FROM Car c JOIN c.owner o`, which still made N+1 queries, but yours worked just fine. Many thanks! I guess I'll just have to live with not using the findXxx methods.

Comment: For convenience methods like that, I would suggest creating a "service layer" or "repository" style class which handles tasks like loading models. This way you could also easily reuse the query without having to duplicate the DQL logic all over the place.

Answer (score 4):

Run first a DQL query where you select all the cars joined (DQL JOIN) with the owner. Put the owner in the `select()`.

```
// preload cars
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('car, owner')
        ->from('\Entity\Car', 'car')
        ->leftJoin('c.owner',  'owner');

    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    // the following seems not needed, but I think it depends on the conf
    $query->setFetchMode("\Entity\Car", "owner", "EAGER");

    $query->execute(); //you don't have to use this result here, Doctrine will keep it
```

Doctrine 2 will then perform a JOIN (normally faster as it requires less db queries depending on the number of records).
Now launch your `foreach`, Doctrine will find the entities internally and it won't run single queries when you need the `owner`.

Monitor the number of queries first/after each change (eg. mysql general log)

Answer (score 1):

Your query...

```
$car->getOwner() // "go and fetch this car's owner"
```

... is in a foreach loop so it will certainly issue the query several times.

If you're writing custom DQL to deal with this, `$car->getOwner()` shouldn't feature in this at all. This is a function of the Car class. The custom DQL you would write would mimick the exact SQL query you point out and get your join done efficiently.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your reply. As long as the owner member is EAGERly loaded, it's not a problem to do `$car->getOwner()` inside the loop. If this just happened with lazy fetching, I would understand, but with eager loading it's not ideal. See my reply to Jani Hartikainen regarding the DQL :-)

Comment: @Frode: Indeed, understand your question better now. Haven't come across this yet and would have expected the same efficiency from the eager loading as you. Looks like DQL is needed.